# Core Data: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have a method which queries Core Data if an object for today already exists.

My code:

```
CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(MRMedSafeAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [cdh context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BMI" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:day];
[comps setMonth:month];
[comps setYear:year];
NSDate *today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

NSLog(@"patient: %@", patient);

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(patient == %@) AND (erstellt_am == %@)", patient, today];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The data model:

bmi.patient is a To-One relationship with Patient.

I don't understand what is wrong, there is not even a ALL or ANY clause in my predicate.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Which specific line of code is the error about? I assume it is the `NSPredicate *pred` but tell us what Xcode tells you.

Comment: It fails after the NSLog line with this message: `CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet. with userInfo (null)
2014-02-28 00:55:06.652 MedSafeStatic[830:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'`

Comment: what is more surprising even, is that it does NOT fail always, it seems that it fails after the method is run a second time...???

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line where you create the NSPredicate. Verify that `patient` and `today` values are what you expect them to be. (Note that your code sample currently does not show how `patient` is created.) What if one of those values ended up being a string that contains the word "ALL" or "ANY"? And verify that the predicate is constructed correctly. Per Apple's predicate programming guide, if `patient` is a key path rather than some sort of object value, you need to use `%K` in your format string instead of `%@`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you handle NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification . or is this it ?

Comment: If you find yourself doing things like this "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];" your architecture is bad. Also note that you ask the calendar for an NSDate and it will return just that: an NSDate, with most likely the time set to midnight. Unless you use identical logic to store the date, you will most likely never find an entity matching that predicate, because no entity will match that data exactly to the second (or even sub-second maybe).

Comment: this looks like the crash is in another thread. what does the stack trace look when you set the exception breakpoint in xcode?

Comment: Please update the question with information such as the error message, rather than putting the information in a comment.  It is usually helpful to diagnose that the problem is intermittent rather than consistent -- it opens the door to a different set of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that there's two threads trying to access the database. Let's not forget that CoreData is non thread safe.

Check your threads and the access to the database as there will be competition in the threads to access the database.

Hope this helps with your problem. If you are accessing the database from different threads try to use completion handlers or KVO notifications in order to manage the thread access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is accessing core data from different threads, you can make sure you use the correct thread with one of the following methods of UIManagedObjectContext:

```
context.performBlockAndWait(block: () -> Void())
context.performBlock(block: () -> Void())
```